# append a string to list in python

Tags: python-2.7, printing, newline

how can I append a long string with newline to a list and keep the 
newline

```
test=[]
test.append({"parameter": ''' hello there
my name is Hamed
how are you
''' })
print(test)
```

when I try this I would get

```
[{'parameter': ' hello there\nmy name is Hamed\nhow are you\n'}]
```

instead of getting hello there\nmy name is Hamed
I am trying to get

```
[{'parameter':     "hello there
 my name is hamed
 how are you?" }]
```

basicaly I am trying to keep the format the same and not use \n. it is important because I am trying to pass a certificate in cloudformation and this format keeps messing up my certificate because it prints the cert with \n and I get certificate is in bad format for example this is the cert I am getting.

```
[{'parameter': '                -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nDX1Wupvv6JP4ReTSq2FRTGNQhh3V\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----'}]
```

Comment: It appears to be working as you expected.  The `\n' is just how whatever you are looking at it with is displaying the newline.

Comment: I am passing this value as a parameter to a variable and when it gets pushed into the new machine it shows \n in the file instead of actually printing the cert in newlines. this would mess up the certificate form. and I get malformed certificate error.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the transport.  How are you `passing` it into the new machine.